# paper js into javascript

Tags: javascript, paperjs

Below are codes through which I was trying to achieve the hue property on a grid of circles.

```
var circles = [];

for(var i=20 ; i<=1500 ; i+=100){
  for(var j=40 ; j<=600 ; j+=110){
    var newCircle = new Path.Circle(new Point(i, j), 20);
    newCircle.fillColor = 'red';
    circles.push(newCircle);
  }
}

function onFrame(event){
  for(var i=0 ; i<circles.length ; i++ ){
    circles[i].fillColor.hue += 1;
  }
}
```

This is the code. Now I am trying to give different colors to each circle using the random color func I created in a seperate JS file but the variables like "num" aren't accessible in that js file.I am not able to link them.

This is the link to codepen : https://codepen.io/akashyap/pen/qMgpGQ

I am not able to figure out the " Using paperscript directly with javascript" section of  :

http://paperjs.org/tutorials/getting-started/using-javascript-directly/

Comment: Can you edit the question and add your random color function, how you're loading it, and how you're trying to call it?

Comment: Hello Jacob ! Thank you for replying. I have attached a link to codepen , please check it out.

Comment: Thanks for providing the code, but please edit the question and add the code there as well. You are also able to do runnable code snippets in Stack Overflow.

Comment: I actually figured it out :p .. But can you please explain how to use paper js directly in Javascript file ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're running across a timing issue. When your plain JS runs, `circles` is not yet defined. That's because your paper script is inside of a `<script type="text/paperscript">` element. This is not natively supported by the browser so it won't be run right away. Rather, some time after you load `paper.js`, it eventually reads your script element and interprets it.

You need to make sure you don't try to access `circles` before it's defined. 
If it is unpredictable when your *paperscript* will be ready, you can use a *callback* to notify external JS when the paperscript has run. For example, if you add this to your paperscript:

```
if (window.onCirclesReady)
  window.onCirclesReady(circles);
```

...you can wrap your JS in this:

```
window.onCirclesReady = circles => {
  // Code here
};
```

This solves two problems. Firstly, you know your JS code won't run until the paperscript has run. Secondly, you are passing the `circles` array so you don't have to use a global variable to make that accessible. You can extend the callback to pass additional data as needed.

[The updates to your CodePen are here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zJeaOj)

Comment: Got it. Thank you so much !